# AngularJS Factory with $resource not able to POST Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to post json data to my service

```
{"firstName":"John"}
```

**Services.js**

```
var AppServices = angular.module('App.services', [ 'ngResource' ]);

AppServices.factory('searchFactory', [ '$resource', function($resource) {

    return $resource('rest/search', {}, {

        update : {
            data : {
                'firstName' : 'john'
            },
            method : 'POST',
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
        }

    });

} ]);
```

**controller.js**

```
var AppControllers = angular.module('App.controllers', []);

AppControllers.controller('SubmitCtrl', [ '$scope', 'searchFactory',
        function($scope, searchFactory) {

            searchFactory.update(function(response) {
                $scope.users = response;
            });

        }

]);
```

Although the request is going out as POST, I don't see above JSON data appended in request body. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't default the post data, you need to pass it in...

```
searchFactory.update({"firstName":"John"}, function(response) {
            $scope.users = response;
        });
```

Docs: [http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/docs/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)